# Keeping PuTTY open after command has run

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm trying to run a remote command on an SSH server via the Remote command field of the PuTTY Configuration dialog (Connection -> SSH) and every time I do the window closes before I've had a chance to read the output of that command.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: http://www.snapfiles.com/screenfiles/putty2.gif]

Any ideas?

Comment: why dont you login and run the command regularly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

putty has a setting to do exactly what you want: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-closeonexit

Answer (score 3):

or add bash to the command :
`ls -ltr ; bash`

Comment: Why? How does it work?

Comment: it will open a shell after all the commands you set and hence stay in input command line mode, and wont close the session

Comment: To find out which shell you are currently using type this command:
echo "$SHELL"

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a `read` to your command, for example:

```
uptime && read
```

This will show the output of `uptime` and then waits for you to press the enter key.

Comment: That works great unless you're connecting to something like a switch or router or something that might not have `read` as a command.